# How to show icon instead of number in JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, imageicon

For saving the database space, I  save numbers instead of icons to database. For example number 9 in database means the B.png. What I want is load the data to `JTable` firstly:

[image]

And then make a loop to change the number to respective icon, such as 9 should be changed to B.png icon:

[image]

But it doesn't work after I loaded the data to the table, the number 9 cell should show icon, but it shows the icon's file path:

[image]

```
  public void load() {
    try {
        conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.30.6/game?autoReconnect=true", "lee", "");
        pstmt = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement("Select c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16,c17 From test_socre order by sn");
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        score.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
        while (rs.next()) {
        }
        DefaultTableCellRenderer centerRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        centerRenderer.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        score.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);
        for (int x = 0; x < score.getColumnCount(); x++) {
            score.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setCellRenderer(centerRenderer);//how to center alignment in jtable
        }
        for (int ix = 0; ix < score.getRowCount(); ix++) {
            for (int jy = 0; jy < score.getColumnCount(); jy++) {
                if (score.getValueAt(ix, jy) != null && "9".equals(score.getValueAt(ix, jy).toString())) {

                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/slip/B.png"));

                    score.setValueAt(icon, ix, jy);
                }
            }
        }

        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm still not sure if I understand the question, but note that the renderer can choose an appropriate icon for each value. Here is what it might look like with the raw numbers on the left table, and icons for the same table model in the table on the right.

[image]

Note particularly the `IconTableCellRenderer` in the code below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ImageForNumberTable {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    String prefix = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/";
    String[] urlStrings = {
        "wCF8S.png", "5v2TX.png", "F0JHK.png", "4EVv1.png", "xj49g.png"
    };
    ImageIcon[] imageIcons = new ImageIcon[5];

    ImageForNumberTable() {
        try {
            initUI();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public final void initUI() throws Exception{
        if (ui!=null) return;
        
        for (int ii=0; ii<urlStrings.length; ii++) {
            URL url = new URL(prefix + urlStrings[ii]);
            imageIcons[ii] = new ImageIcon(url);
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        Integer[][] values = new Integer[5][5];
        for (int xx=0; xx<values.length; xx++) {
            for (int yy=0; yy<values[0].length; yy++) {
                values[xx][yy] = new Integer(random.nextInt(5));
            }
        }
        String[] colNames = {"Col 1", "Col 2", "Col 3", "Col 4", "Col 5"};
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(values, colNames);

        ui = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,2,0,0));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));
        
        JTable table1 = new JTable(dtm);
        table1.setRowHeight(36);
        JTable table2 = new JTable(dtm);
        table2.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new IconTableCellRenderer());
        table2.setRowHeight(36);
        
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(table1));
        ui.add(new JScrollPane(table2));
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }
    
    class IconTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, 
                boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            Component c = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            JLabel l = (JLabel)c;
            final Integer val = (Integer)value;
            l.setIcon(imageIcons[val.intValue()]);
            l.setText("");
            
            return l;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = () -> {
            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (Exception useDefault) {
            }
            ImageForNumberTable o = new ImageForNumberTable();
            
            JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
            
            f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
            f.pack();
            
            f.setVisible(true);
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Has it led you to a solution?

Comment: @AndrewThompson  `table2.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new icontableCellRenderer());`  This line I don't get it. I checked doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultRenderer(java.lang.Class,%20javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer)

Comment: @JianHe *"This line I don't get it."* That line I didn't give. Always copy/paste stuff you're asking about, rather than type 'something like' the line. But even if you'd used the correct upper / lower case, I'd need more detail on what you don't understand before I'd comment. Why don't you ask your own question (in your own question thread, showing more effort than is evident in that comment)?

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the default renderer:

```java
myTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(1)
.setCellRenderer(myTable.getDefaultRenderer(ImageIcon.class));
```

Do this for each cell that has as an input an `ImageIcon`.

Comment: You can't set a renderer for each cell. This method sets the renderer for the entire column.

Answer (score 3):

> but it shows the icon's file path:

You need to tell the table what renderer to use;

If all the data in the table is an `Icon` then you can tell the table to use the default Icon renderer.

First try:

```
table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, table.getDefaultRenderer(Icon.class));
```

If that doesn't work then you can use:

```
JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames)
{
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column)
    {
        return Icon.class;
    }
};
```

If you have a combination of text and Icons then you could use something like:

```
JTable table = new JTable(...)
{
    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column)
    {
        Object value = getValueAt(row, column);

        return getDefaultRenderer(value.getClass();
    }

};
```